# Show that Lebesgue outer measure is not additive even for the finite family of pairwise disjoint sets

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Let $E=[0,1]$. Show that Lebesgue outer measure on $E$ is not additive even for the **finite** family of pairwise disjoint sets.

I can't think about any example where only strict subadditivity holds. Is this even possible?

Comment: Hint: your example will have to make use of non-measurable sets

Comment: For anyone who wants to see how extreme things like this can get, see the math overflow question [Is there a maximum to the amount of disjoint non-measurable subsets of the unit interval with full outer measure?](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/119646/is-there-a-maximum-to-the-amount-of-disjoint-non-measurable-subsets-of-the-unit). Needless to say, you (luka5z) don't need something this extreme for what you're after.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thanks for the link, I wondered about this too. It seems interesting to me. I think in my case there will be some simple example because my book is only the basic introduction.